# How to organize multiple xna game components?

Tags: class, components, xna

I am programming in XNA and need help on organizing my classes and code:
I have a button class and a button manager.
I also have a scene class and a scene manager.

The button manager handles the different buttons that would be drawn on different screens since almost all screens would have a button.
The scene manager does the same thing except instead of handling buttons it handles background scene objects that just need to be drawn.
Both managers depend on the current game state to determine which buttons or scene objects to draw.

How should I organize my code so that both managers know what the current game state is? (Both managers are instantiated inside of the main game class and both managers are game components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for that describes your problem is "Game state management" The XNA website has a few good articles on it, be sure to read this one: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management

Now to answer your question more directly. Say you have 2 different states
-Menu
-Game

First create a class called State with methods to setup draw and update the correct UI elements.

Now create a class MenuState deriving from State and override the setup, draw and update methods.  In the setup method put all the code to generate the correct menu. (Like Scene.MenuItems.Clear(); Scene.MenuItems.Add(new Label(..)); etc..). Do the same for the update and draw methods (update and draw each control, capture events given by clicks on buttons etc...)

Do the same for GameState.

Now in your Scene code make a field "State state".  When a user presses escape set state to (a new) MenuState. When a user returns to game set state to (a new) GameState.  In the scene's update and draw methods place a call to state.Update(..) and state.Draw(..). Because you've overriden these methods in GameState and MenuState the correct actions will be performed.

This approach solves the issue of having a gazzillion controls that do checks like "if(scene.StateEnum == StateEnum.SomeState){DoThis();}". You will find this way easier to manage.

Also think about building other conceptual classes. Like the MenuState could have a substate, "Options menu". Maybe think up a form class, etc...

Answer (score 0):

SInce GameComponent has a Game property, you can use this to cast to the Game class, or alternatively to get a Service exposing the Game Status.